# Pagination with get_posts seems to work but links not showing

Tags: pagination, get-posts

I've a custom page template where I want to query 2 posts from a post type and 1 post from another post type. I have it set up like this:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$articles = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'articles',
  'numberposts' => 1,
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'paged' => $paged
));

$news = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'numberposts' => 2,
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  'paged' => $paged
));

$all_posts = array_merge($articles, $news);
```

Then I do the loop:

```
<? foreach ($all_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post) ?>
  <? get_template_part('content') ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```

And finally I add pagination. I tried WP-PageNavi as well as regular WordPress functions.

```
wp_pagenavi();
next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link();
```

When I go to the page I can see 3 posts as expected (1 article, 2 news) but there is no pagination. If I manually navigate to `/page/2`, `/page/3`, etc. it seems to work and show the next 3 posts but *only* the `previous_posts_link` shows up, not the `next_posts_link` or PageNavi.

The real world example is slightly more complicated and `query_posts` or `WP_Query` are not an option.

How to get pagination working properly?

Comment: pagination functions operate on the global `$wp_query`, WordPress has no knowledge of your custom queries and how many pages should exist, and `wp_pagenavi` needs a query object to read the `max_num_pages`. I think you'll have to build your own pagination from scratch based on the total number of posts available within each distinct query by querying via `WP_Query` to know how many posts are available to each query regardless of page.

Comment: Why does `page/2` `page/3` work then...

Comment: because adding a page number causes the global `paged` var to contain that number. the `previous_posts_link` function simply subtracts 1 from the value of `paged`. but the default query has no pages, which is why you never see a `next_posts_link`.

Comment: @Milo. That's starting to make sense...

Answer (score 2):

Your `$paged` variable on the first is set in the main query. And there is just one page, because it *is* a page. The `get_posts()` calls don't affect that. So the number of all available pages is never higher than the current page, and you cannot get a next page link.

Solution: [filter `pre_get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_posts%20post_type) and set your post types here.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` doesn't work for me in page templates. I tried the simplest example with The Loop in `page-mypage.php` and then `if (is_page('mypage')) { $query->set('post-type', array('articles','news')); }` and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is similar to my problem but there's no asnwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015316/wp-pre-get-posts-not-displaying-posts-on-page

Comment: Also found this which is similar as well http://www.wpaustralia.org/topic/pre_get_posts-and-is_front_page/. So I'm guessing checking for `is_page` doesn't work in `pre_get_posts` so I'm doing this `$query->get('pagename') == 'mypage'` and then set the query but still doesn't work.