# Query specific number of posts for each post type in specific order

Tags: wp-query, pagination, get-posts

This is related to this [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91747/pagination-with-get-posts-seems-to-work-but-links-not-showing), I tried with `get_posts`, `pre_get_posts`, `WP_Query` and basically every option I could find for 2 days now, no solution yet.

The full problem in hand: I have 2 post-types, `articles` and `news`. A post from "news" can be "featured" or "non-featured". I need to query 1 featured news, 4 articles and 2 non-featured news, and display them on a page in that order. The page uses the `page-mypage.php` template.

The posts need to be in that specific order because the size of the post changes  depending on the type and the "featured" meta option. My grid is using Masonry and the sequence that works to have a full grid (no holes or weird empty space) is `featured, article, article, article, article, non-featured, non-featured`.

With the `get_posts` approach in the other question I can't get the pagination working. It works when navigating to `/page/X` but I tried a bunch of custom pagination solutions that didn't work and `paginate_links` which I couldn't get to work either.

So now I'm thinking of using a regular `WP_Query` but how do I tell WordPress I want that many posts from each post-type and in that particular order?

Here's what I really want to do but I can't seem to find a way to do it with `WP_Query` to make pagination work properly (damn pagination!):

```
$articles = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'articles',
  'numberposts' => 4
));

$featured = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'numberposts' => 1,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'featured-news',
      'value' => 'Yes',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
));

$non_featured = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'numberposts' => 2,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'featured-news',
      'value' => 'No',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
));

// Merge in the order I need them to appear
$all_posts = array_merge($featured, $articles, $non-featured);

// The loop
```

Halp!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WP_Query()` with `paged` array key to pass the current page number:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'articles',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
$articles = new WP_Query($args);
////////////////////////////////
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured-news',
                'value' => 'Yes',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'paged' => $paged
    );
$featured = new WP_Query($args);
////////////////////////////////
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured-news',
                'value' => 'No',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'paged' => $paged
    );
$non_featured = new WP_Query($args);
////////////////////////////////
$articles = objectToArray($articles); // objectToArray() function defines below
$featured = objectToArray($featured);
$non_featured = objectToArray($non_featured);
$all_posts = array_merge($featured, $articles, $non_featured);
?>
```

And because you are query-ing from 3 post types, pagination will fail, because it doesn't know from which post type pagination should be based on!

You can use a manual pagination:

```
<?php
// $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if($paged > 1)
{
    echo "<a href=\"".home_url('/')."/page/".($paged-1)."\">Previous page</a>";
}
echo "<a href=\"".home_url('/')."/page/".($paged+1)."\">Next page</a>";
?>
```

Maybe you want change the HREF attr to something else.

**Which I forgot:**

```
<?php
    function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }
        if (is_array($d)) {
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            return $d;
        }
    }
?>
```

WP_Query returns a stdClass Object, first you should convert it to an array like below:

```
<?php
    $articles = objectToArray($articles);
    $featured = objectToArray($featured);
    $non_featured = objectToArray($non_featured);
?>
```

Then merging them. (updated code above)

***Updated***

Another handy way is merging stdClass Objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953077/1906508

Comment: Mmmm, are you sure you can merge WP_Query objects like that. I tried something like this already. I'm using Pagenavi but I'll have a look at the custom pagination.

Comment: @elclanrs updated my post.

Comment: Now that looks better, but what's the point of using `WP_Query` if I end up using a `foreach` with an array? I could also merge posts without `objectToArray` like this I guess: `$all = array_merge($articles->posts, $featured->posts, $non_featured->posts)`.

Comment: @elclanrs that's your force! i don't know which method u care and u want to show the results, but u want `posts_per_page` argument different for each `post_type`. Also you'd better see this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type Also I added a link at the end of my answer.

Comment: I end up not doing this after all, found a better solution with Masonry. The pagination helped tho. Thanks.